# Como atribuir uma class a um tipo de field no Django?

Tags: django

Estou querendo descobrir qual field é um `DateField` e com isso atribuir uma `class='date'`. Como consigo saber o tipo do field?

O código a seguir não funciona mas apresenta a lógica:

```
class MeuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MeuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():                
            if field == "DateField": # (exemplo) como saber que é um DateField?
                field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'date'
```

Comment: `self.fields['DateField'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'date'` não funcionaria neste caso?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 dessa forma eu teria que atribuir `'date'` para cada field, da forma que eu pedi eu atribuo de uma só vez para todos os fields do tipo `DateField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
for field_name, field in self.fields.items():                
    if isinstance(field, forms.DateField):
        field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'date'
```